# egrep xargs: no such file of directory

Tags: regex, grep, xargs

I am trying to find files with some pattern. I use egrep and xargs:

```
egrep -riz "r[ée]section.{,150}(extra.{,5}art)"  /home/data/ | xargs -0 egrep -li "(hanche|bassin|ac[ée]tab|cotyl|iliaque|f[ée]mur)" >> /home/results.txt
```

However, I can see the script actually identifies the correct files in the terminal but I get the following error message ": No such file or directory" and nothing is written into my results.txt file (where ideally I just want the name of the file, not what's inside)? But the file is written, it is just empty. I've looked around this common issue but I can't make it work. It may be the quotes, it may be space characters into file name (which I have not, although I would need the script to work in that case too.). The code is probably a little heavy...

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: `xargs` can be confusing to get working reliably... I think the issue is that you've passed `-0` as a parameter, without converting newlines to null chars. As a quick fix, you should be able to just remove `-0`; as a more "complete" solution, instead use `xargs -d \\n` or `| tr \\n \\0 | xargs -0`

Comment: That's a slight stab in the dark, so didn't want to boldly post it as an answer immediately... If it solves your issue, I'll add it below :)

Comment: Why not reduce your problem to a [mcve] (note: **Minimal**)? Can't you reproduce the problem with 1 file name to search for and 1 regexp per grep command? I bet if you do that you'll figure out the problem for yourself. Btw the `-r` option for `grep` is simply a bad idea someone presumably introduced to `grep` after a weekend of heavy drinking - just use `find` to **find** files (there is a clue in the tool name as to it's purpose!).

Comment: @EdMorton: `after a weekend of heavy drinking` -> lol! I remember you saying another catchy phrase on another using `grep` for exclude files.

Comment: Yeah while I do appreciate and take advantage of many GNU extensions, having `grep` do the same job as `find` is just so ridiculously contrary to the UNIX philosophy and software engineering fundamentals (tight cohesion) in general I'm just stunned anyone ever thought it'd be a reasonable idea!

Comment: @Tom. It doesn't seem to work when I remover -0. Tried the other bit, possibly improperly, and I couldn't get them to work.Eventually I think I found something doing the trick find . -type f -exec egrep -lZ "EXPRESSION1" {} + | xargs -r0 egrep -l "EXPRESSION2" >> /path/to/results.txt